# Open a specific file using string comparaison

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to scan through a list of files and open a specific one.
I have the following condition:

```
Dim f2 As Object
If f2 Like "*DT*" Then....
```

I'd like to add a second condition: if the characters `*+*`, `*&*`, or `*to*` exist in the name, it will skip the file.
Then I'll end up with something like:

```
If f2 Like "*DT*" And Not "*+*, *&*, *to*" Then....
```

So let's say I have the following two files:

```
List DT Q2 2018  
List DT Q2 to Q3 2018
```

My code should only open the first file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you didn't have enough answers on your plate, here is one more :)

I chose to use the `InStr()` function to check for the characters that you want to exclude.

```
Sub LoopFiles()

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\"

    Dim file2 As String
    file2 = Dir(path & "*.xls*")

    Do While Len(file2) > 0

        If InStr(file2, "DT") > 0 And Not (InStr(file2, "+") > 0 Or InStr(file2, "&") > 0 Or InStr(file2, "to") > 0) Then
            Workbooks.Open (path & file2)
        End If

        file2 = Dir    'moves on to the next file
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you would like to test the filename like that

```
Option Explicit

Function openIt(inp As String) As Boolean

    openIt = False

    If inp Like "*DT*" Then
        If inp Like "*+*" Or inp Like "*&*" Or inp Like "*to*" Then
        Else
            openIt = True
        End If
    End If

End Function

Sub testIt()
Dim fname As String

    fname = "List DT Q2 2018"
    'fname = "List DT Q2 to Q3 2018"

    If openIt(fname) Then
        Debug.Print "Open " & fname
    Else
        Debug.Print "No need to open " & fname
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try with below

```
If f2 Like "*DT*" And ((Not (f2 Like "*to*")) And (Not (f2 Like "*&*")) And (Not (f2 Like "*+*"))) Then
```